# Android Image from camera saved with overlay

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, bitmapfactory, android-camera2

I've tried several different ways to get this to work but have come to a halt. I'm getting a photo from the camera and saving it with an overlay.

To combine the images, I have worked out how to do so with two bitmaps and a canvas like so:

```
   Bitmap combined = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight(), null);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combined);

   canvas.drawBitmap(image, new Matrix(), null);
   canvas.drawBitmap(mOverlay, 0,0,null);

   output = new FileOutputStream(new File(mFile.getPath(), mFileName + "(overlay).jpg" ));
   output.write(bytes);
   output.close();
```

The issue is I'm using camera2, which returns an Image. I haven't worked out a way to cast an Image to a Bitmap. I've tried saving the image and then reloading it using BitmapFactory, but frequently end up with OutOfMemory Exceptions.

Has anybody got a way they go around this?

**UPDATE**

```
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImage.getWidth(),mImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    image.copyPixelsFromBuffer(mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().rewind());
```

I stumbled across this in another answer, but I am getting a `Buffer not large enough for pixels` exception, even when I have specified a buffer up to 8x larger than should have been necessary.

Comment: Is both the images are from camera or one is from resource and other is from camera?

Comment: One is from a resource, one is from the camera. The resource picture is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to do this on my own with a lot of various SO answers for each step. It was a bit of trial and error, considering the number of bitmaps I need to manipulate in my app.

A sample of the code to do so is as follows:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = capturedImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];

try {

    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, new BitmapFactory.Options()).copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
    Bitmap combined = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight());
    imageBitmap.recycle();

    //overlay needs to be scaled to image size
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mOverlay, imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight(), false); 
    mOverlay.recycle();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combined);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());

    output = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
    combined.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
    output.close();

    combined.recycle();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unable to combine and save images. " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Hello @dragnflier can you please explain ``mOverlay`` here? Is it GraphicOverlay or any other custom overlay you have built?

Comment: Also if I use GraphicOverlay.java then how can I convert it to bitmap? I am just stuck here